# join values from all tables;

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` double NOT NULL,`value` int, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `updates` (
  `id` double NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` enum('delete','update') DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

And trying to make query which will get all values from `events` and get values from updates, even if `event_id`  in updates do not exist in events table (only possible if action is 'delete')

using

```
SELECT ifnull(e.id,u.event_id) AS event_id,
       e.value,ifnull(u.action,'update') AS ACTION,
       ifnull(u.id,-1) as update_id
        FROM events e 
         LEFT JOIN updates u ON e.id=u.event_id
```

I getting

```
|      EVENT_ID | VALUE | ACTION | UPDATE_ID |
----------------------------------------------
| 1361264148710 |     1 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148711 |     2 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148712 |     5 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148713 |    10 | update |         1 |
| 1361264148714 |    11 | update |         2 |
| 1361264148714 |    11 | update |         3 |
| 1361264148714 |    11 | update |         4 |
| 1361264148715 |    14 | update |         5 |
| 1361264148716 |     1 | update |         6 |
| 1361264148717 |    17 | update |         8 |
| 1361264148718 |    22 | update |        10 |
| 1361264148719 |    23 | update |        11 |
```

my goal is to get:

```
|      EVENT_ID |  VALUE | ACTION | UPDATE_ID |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1361264148710 |      1 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148711 |      2 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148712 |      5 | update |        -1 |
| 1361264148713 |     10 | update |         1 |
| 1361264148714 |     11 | update |         2 |
| 1361264148714 |     11 | update |         3 |
| 1361264148714 |     11 | update |         4 |
| 1361264148715 |     14 | update |         5 |
| 1361264148716 |      1 | update |         6 |
| 1361264148708 | (null) | delete |         7 |
| 1361264148717 |     17 | update |         8 |
| 1361264148709 | (null) | delete |         9 |
| 1361264148718 |     22 | update |        10 |
| 1361264148719 |     23 | update |        11 |
```

[here is sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1eb7/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to `UNION` your results:

```
SELECT ifnull(e.id,u.event_id) AS event_id,
       e.value,ifnull(u.action,'update') AS ACTION,
       ifnull(u.id,-1) as update_id
        FROM events e 
         LEFT JOIN updates u ON e.id=u.event_id
UNION
SELECT u.event_id AS event_id,
       e.value,ifnull(u.action,'update') AS ACTION,
       ifnull(u.id,-1) as update_id
        FROM updates u  
         LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id=u.event_id
     WHERE e.id IS NULL
```

And your updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1eb7/7

As @njk pointed out in the comments, this can be reduced to:

```
SELECT ifnull(e.id,u.event_id) AS event_id,
       e.value,ifnull(u.action,'update') AS ACTION,
       ifnull(u.id,-1) as update_id
FROM
  (SELECT id AS id FROM events
   UNION
   SELECT event_id AS id FROM updates) a
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN updates u ON u.event_id = a.id
ORDER BY update_id
```

Here is the [updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1eb7/16) with both -- I think the first performs better looking at the execution plans.

Comment: but I will need to have `WHERE u.id>N`  it is possible with union ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add WHERE criteria to your UNION -- add it to both -- did you see the updated Fiddle --  looked like your desired results.

Comment: hm, for me it looks very strange that I have to duplicate code for such request,

Comment: @eicto -- the first query gets all your records from the events table where they match in the updates table; the second query gets the ones from the updates table that don't exist in the events table.  Don't think you can do it without a union :)

Comment: @eicto Take a look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02d75/5).. how do you want it sorted?

Comment: I understand how union works, but doesn't it more effective than to use procedure in script to make this join ?

Comment: @njk -- not sure how OP wants it sorted -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02d75/6 seems to match above :)

Comment: @eicto -- I don't know how to do it without a UNION -- I think this is your best option -- best of luck!  njk had a good alternative, but same logic using a UNION...

Comment: thanks @njk , it looks like it better, also I can make conditions in internal `selects` can you place it  as answer ?

Comment: @njk -- see edits -- not sure about performance, but included it nonetheless.  Thanks!

Comment: @eicto -- looking at the execution plan of both queries, it looks like the first performs better.  But I've included njk's answer above.  Best of luck!

Comment: updates will be short table, keeping only last day records, while events can be really big.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24864/discussion-between-eicto-and-sgeddes)

Comment: @sgeddes Your plan is much better.